# JMeter Difference between Samples and thread

Tags: jmeter

I am little bit confused when it comes to samples and threads with loop count
So, If I have 200 threads and 3 loop counts, totals samples The Summary Report are 600.  Does this mean I have 600 users?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't.

- Thread represents a virtual user
- Each thread executes samplers upside down (or according to [Logic Controllers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers))
- Each executed sampler is **sample**
- When thread (virtual user) doesn't have any more samplers to execute and more loops to iterate it's being shut down

Also

- 200 threads doesn't necessarily mean 200 concurrent users as some threads might not have been started yet and some may already be finished. You can visualize real concurrency using i.e. [Active Threads Over Time](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener or set the desired concurrency via [Constant Throughput Timer](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer)

Comment: if the number of users are still same when I use loop count, why do I get server error when I increase the loop count for the same amount of threads?

Comment: because when you increase the loop count you reach something not once/twice but 10-20 times and this does require extra resources. Though, the loopCount==[5-10] usually gives you better results than loopCount==1 (due to the cashing, cookies and all that stuff)

Answer (score 1):

Thread = user,
Sample = one user requesting something to someone

If you have 200 threads you have 200 users, *3 loops = 600 samples (3 for each user/thread).